# A problem in receiving the result of a python code

Tags: python

Since I'm new to python programming, an incorrect result appears when I run the program.
Can anyone assist me whit this, please?

Here is my code:

```
Days = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']

Cash = int(input('Cash ='))

Today = input ('Today is:')

if Today == Days[6]:

    if Cash>2000:
        print('omg lets go shopping')
    else:
        print('get some rest and watch TV')

elif Today == Days[0:5]:

    print('Work hard until you die') 

else:

    print('Today is not in Days')
```

I want "Today" to take exactly the right Day names from the "Days" list and return me the correct answer, but it doesn't.
Besides, if anyone has suggestions about clean coding for this example, I'm looking forward to hearing it

Comment: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](//stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/843953). Also [Fastest way to check if a value exists in a list](//stackoverflow.com/q/7571635/843953)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Today == Days[0:5]
```

This is comparing `Today` to see if it's exactly equal to the *list* `["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]`, which it will never be. If you want to check for list membership, use `in`

```
Today in Days[0:5]
```

Answer (score 0):

`Today == Days[0:5]` will always return `False`, since `Days[0:5]` is a list of strings, while `Today` is a string. You need to do `Today in Days[0:5]` to check if `Today` matches any items in that list.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do `elif Today in Days:` doing `elif Today in Days[0:5]:` wont make a difference. If `Today` was `"Sunday"` then it would match the first `if` condition